# Need to copy all files from one folder to another using java

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, build, copy

Src folder C:\temp
Dest folder C:\temp1

temp has one file (sample.csv)and temp1 folder is empty

I need to copy sample.csv to temp1

**Note:** I cannot specify sample.csv anywhere in code as this name is dynamic.

```
Path temp = Files.move(paths.get(src),patha.get(dest)).
```

This is working only if I give dummy file inside dest directory.
C:\temp1\dummy.csv (i want to specify only C:\temp1 and src folder should go inside temp1)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you please show us your effort as code?

Comment: Path temp = Files.move(paths.get(src),patha.get(dest)).  This is working only if I give dummy file inside dest directory . C:\\temp1\\dummy.csv (i want to specify only C:\\temp1 and src folder should go inside temp1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache commons-io library has a `FileUtils.copyDirectory()` method. It copies all files from source dir and its subfolders to dest dir, creating dest dir if necessary.

[FileUtils docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory(java.io.File,%20java.io.File))

If you are using Gradle, add this to your dependencies section to add this library to your project:

```
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy files from one directory to another one using plain `java.nio`, you could make use of a `DirectoryStream`.

Here's some example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // define source and destination directories
    Path sourceDir = Paths.get("C:\\temp");
    Path destinationDir = Paths.get("C:\\temp1");
    
    // check if those paths are valid directories
    if (Files.isDirectory(sourceDir, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)
        && Files.isDirectory(destinationDir, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
        // if they are, stream the content of the source directory
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(sourceDir)) {
            // handle each file in that stream 
            for (Path fso : ds) {
                /* 
                 * copy it to the destination, 
                 * that means resolving the file name to the destination directory
                 */
                Files.move(fso, destinationDir.resolve(fso.getFileName().toString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can add more checks, like checking if the directories are readable and actually exist. I just put the check for a directory here in order to show the possibilities of the `Files` class.

Comment: I recommend this answer which uses the standard Java API.